# Which one of Django app is better for image resizing (easy-thumbnails or django-imagekit)?

Tags: django, image-processing

I installed django-imagekit, which works well for me, but would like to implement user custom image-cropping (https://github.com/jonasundderwolf/django-image-cropping) which has integration  with easy_thumbnails.

Which one is better to use for Django project to show images in different sizes? What are benefits and disadvantages of each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of these apps serve (slightly) different purposes so you can't really compare them. And if one is better than the other depends on your use case and is quite subjective which is [not a good fit for SO](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

[`easy_thumbnails`](https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails) helps you to quickly generate thumbnails. And of course you can specify the dimensions, scale images and even use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to do all kinds of processing (via Processors). If you "only" need thumbnails i'd say this is the way to go.

[`django-image-cropping`](https://github.com/jonasundderwolf/django-image-cropping) lets you select a part of your image (crop) in the admin and helps you to display the cropped selection (using an easy_thumbnail thumbnail processor) across your page.

I haven't use [`ImageKit`](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-imagekit) but it is advertised as follows:

> ImageKit is a Django app that helps you to add variations of uploaded
>   images to your models. These variations are called “specs” and can
>   include things like different sizes.

So it seems to be similiar to easy_thumbnails as it also comes with [Processors](http://django-imagekit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#processors) and the ability for thumbnail generation.

To me ImageKit seems to be the more powerful option if you need lots of image processing in the backend while the focus of *easy*_thumbnails seems to be *quick* generation of thumbnails.

Comment: One difference between imagekit and easy-thumbnails is that imagekit is more suited for a thumbnail strategy where the thumbnails are created when uploaded while easy-thumbnails is more suited for a strategy where the thumbs are created on the fly (and cached) when requested.